# No setSocketTimeout(timeout) method in org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am using apache HTTP Components 5.1 in my project and I am facing a "SocketTimeOutException". I cannot get the following method to increase the timeout, as in the Apache HTTP client 4.5.13 version: `org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig.setSocketTimeout(timeout)`.

My source code↓

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder;

RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
          .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(5))
          .setConnectionRequestTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(5))
          .setSocketTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(5)).build();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .build();
```

Error↓

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:149)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:241)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:53)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:298)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:175)
at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:218)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionEndpoint.execute(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:583)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.execute(InternalExecRuntime.java:212)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:105)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:182)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:175)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:133)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:75)
```

Comment: Add stacktraces as text not as image. Also add the relevant code

Comment: sorry for the less detail. I updated the httpclient initialization and error stack trace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to migrate setSocketTimeout from httpclient 4 to httpclient 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78078084/how-to-migrate-setsockettimeout-from-httpclient-4-to-httpclient-5)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's now called `setResponseTimeout`, and is available on the builder object: [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html#setResponseTimeout(org.apache.hc.core5.util.Timeout)). It's overloaded to take either a long + `TimeUnit`, or a `Timeout` object.

Comment: Hey Could you please add more details as to how you found this has been replaced. Reading from the documentation, I could not make out this has been replaced with a new name.
I Believe we can use ConnectionConfig.Builder.setSocketTimeout which is available in HttpClient Library 5.2.x

Comment: It's been a while, so I can't remember how I found out. But it seems that `ConnectionConfig` has been re-added in version 5.2. https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/config/ConnectionConfig.html explicitly says "since 5.2".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think setResponseTimeout (as mentioned in another answer) is correct. The RequestConfig setResponseTimeout **is** a new method. However, a response and a socket timeout are not the same thing.

Please see [How to migrate setSocketTimeout from httpclient 4 to httpclient 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78078084/how-to-migrate-setsockettimeout-from-httpclient-4-to-httpclient-5)