# How to use setConnectTimeout() method in org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am updating my project to use HTTP Client 5.2 version and my old code has setConnectTimeout() deprecated method.

It is now replaced with `ConnectionConfig.Builder` but I am not sure how to change the code

Old code:

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig;

public RequestConfig requestConfig() {
   return RequestConfig.custom()
       .setConnectionRequestTimeout(cRtimout)
       .setConnectTimeout(cTimeout)
       .setSocketTimeout(sTimout)
       .build();
}
```

I have referred this stackoverflow link [No setSocketTimeout(timeout) method in org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73711766/no-setsockettimeouttimeout-method-in-org-apache-hc-client5-http-config-request)
and changed the code as below

```
public RequestConfig requestConfig() {
   return RequestConfig.custom()
       .setConnectionRequestTimeout(cRtimout)
       .setResponseTimeout(sTimout) // As socketTimeout is now responseTimout
       .build();
}
```

This RequestConfig is passed to the below code snippet

```
public ClosableHttpClient httpClient(RequestConfig reqConfig,PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnecMgr){

  CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().
         .setDefaultRequestConfig(reqConfig)
         .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnecMgr)
         .setRetryStrategy( // some code block here)
         .build();
}
```

But I am not sure how to change the code for setConnectTimout()

Can someone help on this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example of using `ConnectionConfig` on a Connection Manager in the migration documentation: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/migration-guide/migration-to-classic.html

In this example they use `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`, created with a `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder`.

See this part in particular:

```
.setDefaultConnectionConfig(ConnectionConfig.custom()
              .setSocketTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(1))
              .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(1))
              .setTimeToLive(TimeValue.ofMinutes(10))
              .build())
```

You can probably use another connection manager as well, supposedly it should have same `setDefaultConnectionConfig` method or similar on it's builder.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't see the method setDefaultConnectionConfig() available for Requestconfig, how do we use  ConnectionConfig.Builder.setConnectTimeout(Timeout) in that case? Doc Link -
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html

Comment: It's not going to be in the RequestConfig - but in the place where you pass the RequestConfig to.

Comment: Oh got it, In my case I will be passing RequestConfig object requestConfig to HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig), but it doesn't have the method setDefaultConnectionConfig() . I have updated the post also

Comment: I think I can use setDefaultConnectionConfig() in the place where poolingHttpClientManager is defined. Thank you so much mvmn

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: still couldn't find the setDefaultConnectionConfig() method. Anyone the same?

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/io/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.html#setDefaultConnectionConfig-org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.ConnectionConfig-