# How to migrate setSocketTimeout from httpclient 4 to httpclient 5

Tags: httpclient

I am migrating some code from httpclient4 to httpclient 5. The migration document is lacking.

I had this question and did not find an easy answer online. I asked phind.com and it gave me what I needed. I thought I would post here in case it helps someone else.

Here was my question:

> In apache's httpclient5 library, there is a
> PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager. That has a
> setDefaultConnectionConfig, which takes a ConnectionConfig object
> ConnectionConfig has a setSocketTimeout method.
> PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager also has a setDefaultSocketConfig
> that takes a SocketConfig method. SocketConfig has a setSoTimeout.
> What is the difference between the socket timout passed to
> ConnectionConfig versus socket timeout passed via SocketConfig?

I then asked this follow-up question:

> In httpclient4, we set socket timeout via
> RequestConfig.setSocketTimeout. Was that comparable to the socket
> timeout in ConnectionConfig or SocketConfig in httpclient5?

And finally this third question:

> If you set the timeout via SocketConfig, do you need to set it in
> ConnectionConfig, also, or does setting it in ConnectionConfig not
> have any effect if set in SocketConfig?

Edit: And then I asked a 4th question about response timeout.

I will post the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer to First Question

In the Apache HttpClient 5 library, both `ConnectionConfig` and `SocketConfig` are used to configure various aspects of the socket and connection, but they serve different purposes and have different impacts on the behavior of the HttpClient.

- **ConnectionConfig**: This is used to configure various aspects of the connection, such as the buffer size, the maximum line length, and the socket timeout. The socket timeout set through `ConnectionConfig` applies specifically to the socket timeout for the connection, which is the amount of time the client will wait for data after establishing a connection before giving up. This is particularly useful for handling scenarios where the server might not respond immediately after the connection is established.
- **SocketConfig**: This is used to configure lower-level socket parameters, such as the socket timeout, the buffer sizes, and the keep-alive settings. The socket timeout set through `SocketConfig` applies to the socket timeout for all operations on the socket, including connection establishment, read operations, and write operations. This is more general and affects the overall behavior of the socket.

The key difference between the socket timeout passed to `ConnectionConfig` and the socket timeout passed via SocketConfig lies in their scope and application:

- The socket timeout in `ConnectionConfig` specifically applies to the connection phase, affecting how long the client will wait for a response after establishing a connection.
- The socket timeout in `SocketConfig` applies more broadly to all socket operations, including connection establishment, reading from, and writing to the socket.

In practice, if you're configuring the HttpClient and need to set a socket timeout, you might use `SocketConfig` for a more global configuration that affects all socket operations. If you need to set a timeout specifically for the connection phase, you might use `ConnectionConfig`. However, it's important to note that these settings can be combined to provide a comprehensive configuration for the HttpClient's behavior.

## Answer to Follow-up Question

In Apache HttpClient 4, setting the socket timeout via `RequestConfig.setSocketTimeout` is comparable to setting the socket timeout in `SocketConfig` in HttpClient 5. Both configurations deal with the maximum amount of time the client will wait for a response from the server before throwing an exception, which is essentially the socket timeout setting.

- **HttpClient 4**: The socket timeout is set using `RequestConfig.setSocketTimeout(int soTimeout)`, where soTimeout is the timeout in milliseconds. This configuration is applied to the entire request execution, including the connection, sending the request, and receiving the response. It's a high-level configuration that can be applied to individual requests or as a default for all requests made by the HttpClient instance 4611.
- **HttpClient 5**: The socket timeout is set using `SocketConfig.setSoTimeout(int soTimeout)`, where soTimeout is the timeout in milliseconds. This configuration is also applied to the entire request execution and is comparable to the socket timeout in HttpClient 4. It affects how long the client will wait for a response after establishing a connection, sending the request, and waiting for the response data 2.

The key difference between the two is the context in which they are applied:

- In **HttpClient 4**, the socket timeout is applied at the request level through `RequestConfig`, which allows for fine-grained control over the timeout settings for individual requests.
- In **HttpClient 5**, the socket timeout is applied at the socket configuration level through `SocketConfig`, which affects all socket operations performed by the HttpClient.

Both configurations serve the purpose of setting a timeout for the entire request-response cycle, ensuring that the client does not wait indefinitely for a response. However, the way they are applied and managed in HttpClient 4 and HttpClient 5 differs due to the evolution of the library and its architecture.

## Answer to 3rd Question

When you set the socket timeout via `SocketConfig` in HttpClient 5, it applies to all socket operations, including the connection phase, read operations, and write operations. This means that if you set the socket timeout in `SocketConfig`, it will be used for all connections managed by the `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` unless overridden at the request level.

Setting the socket timeout in `ConnectionConfig` is specifically for configuring the connection phase, including the socket timeout for the connection itself. However, if you've already set a socket timeout in `SocketConfig`, it will generally override the socket timeout set in `ConnectionConfig` for all operations. This is because `SocketConfig` is a more global configuration that affects all socket operations, including those related to the connection phase.

Therefore, if you set the socket timeout in `SocketConfig`, you typically do not need to set it again in `ConnectionConfig` for the same socket operations, as the setting in `SocketConfig` will apply. However, if you want to have different socket timeouts for different types of operations or connections, you might still need to use both `SocketConfig` and `ConnectionConfig` in conjunction.

It's important to note that RequestConfig settings, which can include socket timeouts, apply only after the HTTPS connection has been fully established. Until then, only `SocketConfig` settings apply. This distinction is crucial for secure connections, which need to perform an SSL/TLS handshake before they can be used to execute requests 1.

In summary, setting the socket timeout in `SocketConfig` will generally override any socket timeout set in `ConnectionConfig` for the same operations, making `SocketConfig` the primary place to configure socket timeouts for most use cases. However, if you need to specify different timeouts for different connections or operations, you might still need to use both configurations in conjunction.

## BONUS: 4th Question - Response Timeout

(I also asked about how there is now a response timeout method in `RequestConfig`, where I saw no response timeout in the httpclient4 API.) Here was the response:

Yes, it's true that in HttpClient 4, there wasn't a direct way to set a response timeout similar to the setResponseTimeout method available in HttpClient 5. HttpClient 4 primarily focused on setting connection, connection request, and socket timeouts, but not specifically a response timeout that applies to the entire duration of waiting for a response from the server after the request has been sent.

- **Connection Timeout**: This is the timeout for establishing the connection to the server. It's set using RequestConfig.setConnectTimeout(int connectTimeout).
- **Connection Request Timeout**: This is the timeout for waiting for a connection from the connection manager. It's set using RequestConfig.setConnectionRequestTimeout(int connectionRequestTimeout).
- **Socket Timeout**: This is the timeout for waiting for data after the connection has been established. It's set using RequestConfig.setSocketTimeout(int soTimeout).

For scenarios where you need to ensure the entire request-response cycle does not exceed a certain duration, HttpClient 4 users often had to implement custom mechanisms, such as using a Timer to abort the request if it takes too long, as shown in the example from 2. This approach, however, is more of a workaround and not a built-in feature of the library.

In contrast, HttpClient 5 introduced the setResponseTimeout method on the RequestConfig builder, which allows for the direct setting of a response timeout that covers the entire request-response cycle, providing a more straightforward and integrated way to control this aspect of the request execution.